# Read message by sequence in socket

Tags: ios, sockets

I have build a socket to transfer message between client and server on IOS.

```
if(CFReadStreamSetClient(readStream, registeredEvents, readCallBack, &myContext))
{
    CFReadStreamScheduleWithRunLoop(readStream, CFRunLoopGetCurrent(), kCFRunLoopCommonModes);
}

if (!CFReadStreamOpen(readStream)) {
    CCLog("Error Open Read Stream");
    /* error handling */
}
```

and readCallBack function

```
void readCallBack(CFReadStreamRef stream, CFStreamEventType eventType, void *clientCallBackInfo)
    {
        switch(eventType) {
            case kCFStreamEventHasBytesAvailable:{
                UInt8 bufr[10240];
                int bytesRead  = CFReadStreamRead(stream, bufr, sizeof(bufr));
                if(bytesRead >0 ){
                    NSLog(@"Read: %d", bytesRead);
                }
                break;
            }
            case kCFStreamEventErrorOccurred:
                NSLog(@"A Read Stream Error Has Occurred!");
            case kCFStreamEventEndEncountered:
                NSLog(@"A Read Stream Event End!");
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
```

But when client send multi message to server by multi time.

Server always read it as one message.

Example:

Client send message 1st: Message1

Client send message 2nd: Message2

But when server read message from client:

Result is: Message1Message2

How can i split it as 2 messages. (I don't know the size of each message)

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to make up a protocol of your own. For example, clients can append `\n` to each message so that the server can split messages by `\n`. However if your messages can have `\n` character in them, you can modify your protocol to first send the length of the message, again split by `\n`:

Client sends: `8\nMessage1`

Client sends: `14\nAnotherMessage`

Server receives: `8\nMessage114\nAnotherMessage`

So you read up to first `\n` and get the content length. Then you read that many characters.

Be careful with the difference between byte streams and text streams though. You can google about TCP text streams to learn more about them. Your best bet is to send number of bytes being sent, instead of number of characters.

And be aware that sometimes, you will not receive a message as a whole. For example the following is possible:

Client sends: `8\nMessage1`

Client sends: `14\nAnotherMessage`

Server receives: `8\nMessage11`

Server receives: `4\nAnotherMessage`

Comment: Yes. I see. But we have a problem. I client message too long. My buffer not enough. That mean i can not read full message. Because my message as a json. If my message not enough. that mean i can not pares it to NSDictionary. Thanks

Comment: What's the problem with message being too long?

Comment: But the if we have solution to read message from client as 2 two message. Not one message. Do you have any solution for that? Thanks.

Comment: No, that is impossible to do with pure sockets. I have no solution for that. Nobody has any solution for that. You should learn more about sockets.

Comment: You have to gather all incoming data somewhere (buffer/array/whatever) and after each packet you receive, check that to see if there's a whole message in there. Remove that, parse your message and keep doing the same thing.